# シェルスクリプト（CSH）の暗号化方法

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Windows Script Encoderを利用してVBSをVBEへ暗号化するように、CSHのソースコードを暗号化して実行することは可能ですか？  
可能であれば方法を教えてください。
Bashなどで代用可能であればそれでも構いません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら [How to Encrypt Your Bash Shell Script on Linux Using SHC](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/) などが参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 方法としてすごく参考になりました。ありがとうございます。ただ、シェル暗号する前にもう少し違うアプローチを考えた方がいいって書いてますね。。。
まずは一旦このやり方を試してみようと思います！！

Comment: [シェル・スクリプトを難読化 (obfsh)](http://www.natzworks.com/digital/2010/409.html)や[シェル・スクリプトをバイナリ化 (shc)](http://www.natzworks.com/digital/2010/410.html)も参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @Shinya コメントで満足した回答が得られたのであれば、ご自分でその内容を整理して「回答」として投稿しましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。記事読ませていただきました。暗号化とありましたが目的はソースコードの隠ぺいでありバイナリ化で実現できるので回答として投稿しました。

Answer (score 1):

暗号化ではないですが、シェルファイルのコンパイラSCHを利用することで、シェルのバイナリ化が行えソースコードの隠ぺいが可能になります。

[Manpage for shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html)